# Android Stack Exchange app keeps crashing when I check Achievements

Tags: bug, android-app

Over the last day, every time I tried to check the Achievements the app crashes, even just after the app launch. Here's a snippet of the error report I sent:

> [image]

I'm not sure if it's related, but my app also still displays the Embedded Engineering site which was closed as `Unknown Site embedded` which also crashes the app if selected.

Comment: Did you try restarting the device? Clearing the app cache?

Comment: Same NPE in AchievementListAdapter here using the new 1.0.73 beta on both a Nexus 6 Android 5.1.1 and Galaxy Tab 8.4 Android 4.4.2. The Achievements page loads fine but when I scroll to the bottom of the list it always crashes. I tried clearing the app cache on both devices and restarting but it still occurs.

Comment: There's a possibility that the closed site is the cause of this bug, probably related to how SE API handles closed site's achievements. Just to make sure, did you get any reps/badges on that site? When was it closed?

Comment: Yes, it's related to the closed site, quite sure of that by now.